# Mod-Rewrite - Need two different redirection rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to have two different redirects; one redirection if a user accesses an index.php-file on my apache-server and one redirection after a user enters a particular url.

So my index.php file lies in "/client/frontend/questionnaire"-folder on my apache. If a user enters "www.test-domain.com" he or she should be redirected to the index.php - file on the server.

The second redirection should be processed if a user enters "www.test-domain.com/news". Then he or she should be redirected to "www.test-domain.com/client/frontend/app/index.php/article-one".

I managed to create the first rewrite rule like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ client/frontend/questionnaire/index.php [L]
```

But I do not know how to create the second rule.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use multiple `RewriteCond`+`RewriteRule`. See the [`mod_rewrite` introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/intro.html#rewritecond) and then the [reference documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (all is explain).

Just the `RewriteRule` actually rewrite the current request. To execute it, all `RewriteCond` before must be `true`.

Samples from the documentation:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.2\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://intranet.example.com$1

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^host1  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^host2  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^host3
RewriteRule ...some special stuff for any of these hosts...

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (iPhone|Blackberry|Android)
RewriteRule  ^/$                 /homepage.mobile.html  [L]
```

Comment: Could you please provide me a bit more information?

Comment: I complete the answer and I suggest you to read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nicolas. I tried it like the following:  

Options -Indexes  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*nmo-online.com$
RewriteRule ^$ client/frontend/questionnaire/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (.*)weather(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ client/frontend/app/index.php [L]  The condition works but the second does not.

Comment: Well, I think I got it, thanks for your help Nicolas!